# Android incoming call slider

Tags: android, call

On the Android call screen (at least on Froyo) the incoming call screen has what i have to call a slider that you hold and slide in the opposite direction to unveil the next screen.  is this view available to me.  I would like to use it but im not sure what its called if it is so searching becomes difficult.  I found this link but i dont im wondering if the incoming call screen view slider is included in any API call directly.

http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/29/android-switching-screens-by-dragging-over-the-touch-screen/

and here is a link to what im looking for:
http://cdn.androidtapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/lock-20-charging.jpg

or
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-_jWcJnNOAUI/Tm5U4eP5CYI/AAAAAAAAABo/Y9QfRchcJh8/s1600/android.jpg

update: I also found the source for what i now believe its called "sliding tab"
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/widget/SlidingTab.java

but it does not look public, so i guess this is resolved in the fact that i could just copy the private source over in eclipse.

Comment: Please clarify: What are you searching for? Are you searching for a UI Widget for use in Android Apps which provides the same functionality or are you trying to modify the behaviour in the lockscreen or something completely different?

Comment: Hi, i have my own app.  What i want is to use the "slide lock" view to replace buttons.  I like feel of it.  I have updated the opening description with photos.